# Find the solution to $x=\log_{10}(\log_{10}(\log_{10}(x)))$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is one practice in my real analysis class on proof writing. Is my proof completely solid? Is there anything to be improved on on the logic? Thanks in advance

Problem: Find the solution to $x=log_{10}(log_{10}(log_{10}(x)))$

My attempt:

+Let $f:(0,+\infty] \rightarrow R$ be defined by:
$$f(x)=x-log_{10}(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{xln(10) }$$
We have:$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f'(x)=0\Leftrightarrow  x=\frac{1}{ln10}\\ 
f'(100)>0\\
f'(0.1)<0
\end{matrix}\right.$

and   $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{f(x)=+\infty}$

$\Rightarrow $ f(x) attains its local and global minimum at $x=\frac{1}{ln10}$

$\Rightarrow $$f(x)\geq f(\frac{1}{ln10})>0$ ∀ $x\in(0,+\infty]$ $(1)$

$$$$

+Let $f_1(x)=f(x)$
and $(f_n)_{n\in N}:A_n\subset (0,+\infty] \rightarrow R$ be defined as:

$$f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(log_{10}(x))$$

By (1),  $∀n\in N,f_n(x)>0$  $∀ $ $x\in A_n$

Let $(g_n)_{n\in N}:A_n\rightarrow R$ be defined as: 
$g_n=x-log_{10}(log_{10}(log_{10}(...(x))))$ (n 
times)

$\Rightarrow ∀n\in N,g_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n{f_n(x)}>0$ $∀ $ $x\in(0,+\infty]$

$\Rightarrow g_3(x)=x-log_{10}(log_{10}(log_{10}(x)))$ >0 $∀ $ $x\in(0,+\infty]$

Hence the equation $x=log_{10}(log_{10}(log_{10}(x)))$ has no solution

Comment: You're working too hard. $x \ge 0$, trivially. $10^x > x$ as it always has gradient > 1, and $10^0 > 0$. So $x > log_{10}(x) > log_{10}(log_{10}(x))$ ...

Comment: Yup my idea is basically the same.What is your advice on making it shorter?

Comment: My last comment contains most of what you need. You should take the derivative of $10^x$ properly to show it is >1, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: if $x$ is a solution, then

- one must have $x>0$;
- Also, $f(x)>0$ and $f(f(x))>0$ where $f(y)=\log_{10}(y)$ in increasing.
- $x>f(x)$.